# Timestamp to Date issue

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I'm trying to create a function that convert a timestamp to Date object.

My problem is that using [this online tools](http://www.timestampconvert.com) i reach correctly to convert timestamp to date but using java it doesn't convert correctly.

This is what i try:

```
public static Date getDateFromUUID(UUID uuid) {
    Calendar uuidEpoch = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    uuidEpoch.clear();
    uuidEpoch.set(1582, 9, 15, 0, 0, 0);
    long epochMillis = uuidEpoch.getTime().getTime();
    long time = (uuid.timestamp() / 10000L) + epochMillis;

    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    start.setTimeInMillis(time*1000);
    end.set(start.get(Calendar.YEAR), start.get(Calendar.MONTH), start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),0,0,0);
    return end.getTime();
}
```

I'm trying using that uuid: `a261ae00-2a9c-11b2-ae56-bcee7be23398`

it correctly converts to timestamp : `1406412000`

Using this:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
start.setTimeInMillis(time*1000);
end.set(start.get(Calendar.YEAR), start.get(Calendar.MONTH), start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),0,0,0);
return end.getTime();
```

I need to remove hours, minutes and seconds and take only years,months and days.
but it convert timestamp to

```
Sat Jul 26 02:00:00 CEST 2014
```

Instead of

```
Sun Jul 27 00:00:00 CEST 2014
```

what could be my mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your time zone if wrong. Notice that output is `CEST` but you set the calendar to `UTC`. The delta between these two is 2 hours. When you output the Date you need to set the timezone appropriately.

Comment: i don't need to output my Date but to check if that date is equals to other.. how can i solve?

Comment: Should be equal as long as the underlying millis since epoch are the same. This doesn't take time zone into account. If they are unequal your post about `02:00:00 CEST` is misleading. You need to provide the equality that is failing. Do a get millis on both values and compare them. Should point you in the right direction.

Comment: so you say to check if timestamp are equals? if so i need to check only the day-month-year and not hours-minutes-seconds. How can i do by code?

Comment: I think you need to re-ask or edit your question showing the code that is failing. The above question's issue (being 2 hours off) has been answered. It is too hard to guess what else is going wrong without explicit code showing us what is failing.